# I want ['False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True'] not [False, False, False, True, True]

Tags: python, list, for-loop

When getting the output of the for loop in a list, I want the result in multiple items not the whole result in just 1 item.

```
my_string = "888wT"
the_issue = []


for char in my_string:
    the_issue.append(char.isalpha())
```

I want the result to be this: Desired result: ['False', 'False',  'False',  'True',  'True']

but the output is the next: [False, False, False, True, True]

Comment: So you need to turn each boolean into a string?

Comment: Easy: `map(str, ...)`

Comment: `append(str(char.isalpha()))`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "multiple items not the whole result in just 1 item"? The difference between `['False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True']` and `[False, False, False, True, True]` isn't the number of items, it's the datatype of those items (str vs bool).

Comment: What would `str("a".isalpha())` output?

Comment: That's a strange result to want.

Comment: @wim "The heart wants what the heart wants" :)

Comment: Why on earth do you want strings instead of booleans? 

Also, it's wasteful to build a list up by `append`ing one item at a time. Just do `the_issue = [char.isalpha() for char in my_string]`.  Or replace `char.isalpha()` with `str(char.isalpha())` if you really want strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
my_string = "888wT"
the_issue = []


for char in my_string:
    if char.isalpha():
        the_issue.append('True')
    else:
        the_issue.append('False')


print(the_issue)
```

You need to append to the list an String value instead of a Boolean value.

Comment: And what would a nicer way of converting look like?  :)

Comment: This is not the most elegant way to do it, but the answer is not wrong. @CristiFati

Comment: @Lucas: but it's still quite a difference to OPs code. Why not use OP's code and just add 5 characters to it?

Answer (score -1):

you could try list comprehension:

```
string = "888wT"
the_issue = [str(item.isalpha()) for item in string]
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but is this not the same answer as given 10 mins ago by @subhash-prajapati?

Comment: yes it is. I just didnt know it exists when i wrote mine